# Binding em campo de texto

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Em meu projeto tenho algumas tabelas entre elas uma de ocorrências e uma de usuários, onde um relacionamento entre elas de várias ocorrências para um usuário.

O que acontece é que na hora de cadastrar uma ocorrência eu tenho que referenciar o usuário, até ai tudo bem, só que como usei o *scaffolding* para criar a *view* e *controller*, cria-se um *select list* e nele se escolhe o usuário.

Mas não é assim que quero, pois quero que pegue o *ID* do usuário logado e salve no banco, que já consigo pegar esse *ID* do usuário logado, e na view ao invés de um *select list* tenha um campo de texto e nele mostre o nome do usuário, e não o *ID*. Ou seja algo parecido com o que ocorre na criação de um *select list*. Ele faz um *bind* e mostra o nome e não o *ID*, mas o salva no banco.

O *select list* é montado assim:

## No Controller

E só pra deixar mais claro, esse código do *controller* está comentado pois não estou usando um *select list*, estou colocando ele aqui, pra caso alguém saiba uma lógica para fazer com o campo de texto, receba o *ID* mas mostre o nome do usuário,assim como ocorre em um *select list*, e que isso que se estenda para na hora de visualizar qual o usuário que deu aquela ocorrência.

No *Get*

```
ViewBag.UsuarioID = new SelectList(db.Usuarios, "UsuarioID", "Nome");
```

No *Post*

```
ViewBag.UsuarioID = new SelectList(db.Usuarios, "UsuarioID", "Nome", ocorrencia.UsuarioID);
```

## Na View

```
@model SisGAL.Models.Ocorrencia

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Novo";
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Mascara.js"></script>
    var diaAtual = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy");
}

<style>
    a {
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        color: white;
    }

        a:link {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a:visited {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a:active {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
</style>

<h2>Nova</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Ocorrencia</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TipoOcorrencia, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TipoOcorrencia, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.DropDownList("Tipo", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TipoOcorrencia, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CausaOcorrencia, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
               @* @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CausaOcorrencia, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.DropDownList("Causa", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CausaOcorrencia, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DescricaoOcorrencia, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DescricaoOcorrencia, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.DescricaoOcorrencia, new { cols = 50, rows = 6, htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DescricaoOcorrencia, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
               @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Status, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.DropDownList("Status", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataOcorrencia, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataOcorrencia, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" id="DataOcorrencia" name="DataOcorrencia"
                       placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa" onkeyup="formataData(this,event);" maxlength="10" value="@diaAtual" readonly>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataOcorrencia, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AlunoID, "AlunoID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
               @* @Html.DropDownList("AlunoID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })*@
                @Html.Awe().Lookup("AlunoID")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AlunoID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @*@Html.DropDownList("UsuarioID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })*@
                <input type="text" class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" id="UsuarioID" name="UsuarioID"
                       value="@User.Identity.Name" readonly>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" class="btn btn-success" />
                <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Alunoes")" style="padding-left: 112px;"><input type="button" value="Cancelar" class="btn btn-warning" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    <span class="btn btn-default">@Html.ActionLink("Voltar para Lista", "Index")</span>    
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Então como que eu poderia fazer esse *bind* e mostrar o nome o usuário em um  campo de texto e salvar no banco o *ID* ? Ou seja, vincular os dois.

## Edit

O que tá acontecendo é que na hora de salvar o usuário em uma ocorrência, o campo espera um *long*, por causa que foi assim que declarei o *ID*, e eu estou colocando uma *string* com o nome do usuário logado. E que na hora de listar e mostrar o usuário, mostre o nome dele, e não o *ID*.

## Action que salva os dados

```
  public ActionResult Novo([Bind(Include = "OcorrenciaID,TipoOcorrencia,CausaOcorrencia,DescricaoOcorrencia,Status,DataOcorrencia,AlunoID,UsuarioID")] Ocorrencia ocorrencia)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Ocorrencias.Add(ocorrencia);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        /*ViewBag.AlunoID = new SelectList(db.Alunos, "AlunoID", "NomeAluno", ocorrencia.AlunoID);*/
        /*ViewBag.UsuarioID = new SelectList(db.Usuarios, "UsuarioID", "Nome", ocorrencia.UsuarioID);*/
       // ViewBag.UsuarioID = ("UsuarioID", "Nome", ocorrencia.UsuarioID);
        Ocorrencias();
        return View(ocorrencia);
    }
```

## A parte do relacionamento no Model

```
 [Display(Name = "Usuário")]
 public long UsuarioID { get; set; }
 public Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
```

Comment: Está muito confusa sua pergunta. Você pode usar as opções do scaffolding ou simplesmente escolher uma opção que ele não gere os controles. Assim você cria seus controles (textbox, dropdown, etc) como quiser. Não da para saber se você está com dificuldade em montar a View ou dificuldade para gravar no banco.

Comment: Foi o que pensei, que ficaria. Então o que acontece é que na *view*, na hora de salvar o Usuário, o campo espera um *long* e eu estou salvando uma *string*. E eu queria que mostrasse a *string* no campo de texto, mas salvasse o *long*... Assim como acontece no *select list*. Acho que agora ficou melhor né ?

Comment: Onde você colocou "No Controller" na sua pergunta, não seria código que está na sua View? "UsuarioID" recebe um "SelectList" mesmo? Se puder, insira como está sua View e Controller para tentarmos ajudar.

Comment: @Renan, feito !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como no *DropDownList* você colocou `value="@User.Identity.Name"`, no post do formulário você receberá o nome do usuário e não o ID.

Uma alternativa seria você usar um *hidden* com o valor do ID do usuário que você deseja receber no post.

---

Edição:

> Eu estava pensando nisso, mas será que poderia colocar em código ? E não do DropDownList e sim um campo de texto mesmo, não quero dropdown.

Controller:

```
public class SeuController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CadastrarOcorrencia()
    {
        var usuarioLogado = ObterUsuarioLogado();
        ViewBag.UsuarioID = usuarioLogado.Id;
        ViewBag.UsuarioNome = usuarioLogado.Nome;
        return View();
    }
}
```

View com um *textbox* exibindo o nome do usuário logado:

```
@Html.Hidden("UsuarioID", (string)ViewBag.UsuarioID)
@Html.TextBox("UsuarioNome", (string)ViewBag.UsuarioNome)
```

Comment: Eu estava pensando nisso, mas será que poderia colocar em código ? E não do *DropDownList* e sim um campo de texto mesmo, não quero *dropdown*.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que eu entendi você está colocando no `User.Identity.Name` o nome do usuário e o que você precisa é o ID. Logo você tem que buscar no bando o ID que corresponde o Nome que está no `User.Identity.Name`.

Então no seu `Controller` faça o seguinte:

```
ViewBag.UsuarioIDLogado = db.Usuarios.First(x=>x.Nome == User.Identity.Name).ID;
```

Na `View`:

```
@Html.Hidden("UsuarioID", ViewBag.UsuarioIDLogado })
```

Na `Action` de Salvar faça o seguinte:

```
public ActionResult Novo([Bind(Include = "OcorrenciaID,TipoOcorrencia,CausaOcorrencia,DescricaoOcorrencia,Status,DataOcorrencia,AlunoID,UsuarioID")] Ocorrencia ocorrencia, string UsuarioID)
    {
        long convertUsuarioID;
        long.TryParse(UsuarioID, out convertUsuarioID);
        ocorrencia.UsuarioID = convertUsuarioID;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Ocorrencias.Add(ocorrencia);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        /*ViewBag.AlunoID = new SelectList(db.Alunos, "AlunoID", "NomeAluno", ocorrencia.AlunoID);*/
        /*ViewBag.UsuarioID = new SelectList(db.Usuarios, "UsuarioID", "Nome", ocorrencia.UsuarioID);*/
       // ViewBag.UsuarioID = ("UsuarioID", "Nome", ocorrencia.UsuarioID);
        Ocorrencias();
        return View(ocorrencia);
    }
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54608/discussion-on-answer-by-diego-zanardo-binding-em-campo-de-texto)